# Trying to change Excel Column to Text

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to format all Excel cells starting at "A3" using the TEXT function. I am able to do one cell(see Example 1) but I am having issues trying to do whole column, I keep getting a mismatch error(see Example 2).

- CODE

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim lastRow As Integer
LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

- Example 1

```
ws.Range("H3") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(ws.Range("A3"), "00000.0000")
```

- Example 2

```
ws.Range("H3:H" & LastRow) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(ws.Range("A3:A" & LastRow), "00000.0000")
```

Error: Mismatch error runtime error 13

Comment: Side note: do you actually want text, or do you want to apply a text format? They're not the same. e.g. `ws.Range("A3:A" & LastRow).NumberFormat = "00000.0000"`.

Comment: I want to apply the TEXT format.

Comment: Then the provided line of code should be sufficient.

Comment: That's what I thought but I keep getting the mismatch error.

Comment: ... the line of code provided in the first comment.

Comment: The first code is only changing the first cell, I need all the cells to change.

Comment: `ws.Range("A3:A" & LastRow).NumberFormat = "00000.0000"`.

Comment: the problem is that I need to have leading zeros and this doesn't. e.g "A1" has this information 00123.0012 but when you look at the formula bar, the value is showing as 123.0012. I need formula bar value to have it as 00123.0012 so that's the reason I am using the TEXT function to stored those number as "text" on another column to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Application.Text`, which is the late-bound version of `WorksheetFunction.Text` and can accept and return an array.

Also change `Integer` to `Long` to avoid a potential `Overflow` error. Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With ws.Range("H3:H" & lastRow)
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = Application.Text(ws.Range("A3:A" & lastRow), "00000.0000")
End With
```